# VirtualBox: same virtual machine in a shared folder result in file not accesible every time an user saves the state of the machine

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, shared-folders, sharing

I have created a shared folder in /Users/shared_folder. I have [moved the virtual box files](https://superuser.com/a/400389/218025) to that folder `/Users/shared_folder/.VirtualBox VMs/`

I have set the whole folder with all the permissions: `sudo chmod -R 777 shared_folder`. I have switched to the other user, and I have executed the same command. I also have tried with the following command as [I read here](https://superuser.com/questions/126073/chmod-to-allow-read-and-write-permissions-for-directory) (without knowing what I was doing by the way): `find somedir \( -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx {} \; -o -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} \; \)`

Both users can access the same virtual machine... Till some of them save the machine state. Then, the other user cannot access because of not enough reading permissions.

How could I share the same virtual machine with both users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have copied one different *VirtualBox VMs* folder to each user folder. Then I have executed the command `sudo chmod -R 777 MyVirtualBoxFolder` within each user's account to correct the permissions. Finally changing the preferences as it is described here: https://superuser.com/a/400389/218025

However if you want to have one virtual hard disk shared between all users (because your hard disk is not very big, for example), my next approach was going to be to create the following script:

```
if [ stat -c %U MyVirtualBoxFolder ] 
then
    echo "You are the owner"
else
    echo “Changing permissions of /Users/shared_folder/.VirtualBox VMs/“
    sudo chmod -R 777 MyVirtualBoxFolder
fi

echo "Opening VirtualBox…”
virtualbox
```

Notice I have not tested the command `stat -c %U MyVirtualBoxFolder`. I have just copied it from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19003/91196

The idea is simple, before opening VirtualBox, check if the permissions are correct. If not, correct them before launching VirtualBox.

---

**UPDATE**:

Maybe it is better to create a script that just change the permissions always before opening VirtualBox:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 MyVirtualBoxFolder
virtualbox
```

The only issue to reach perfection is that the user must type its password always to open VirtualBox (and must be admin by the way!)